# Access SQL Query, Returning 6 Counts from 1 Table Based on Dates

Tags: sql, ms-access

Sorry if this question has been asked before, my database table is structured like this:

```
AgentName | Sold1 | SoldDate1 | Sold2 | SoldDate2 | Sold3 | SoldDate3
Geoff     | True  | 20/06/2012 | False | Null     | True  | 20/04/2012
Alex      | True  | 13/02/2012 | True  | 26/06/2012 | False | Null
```

Basically what I am trying to do is to count how many Geoff has sold in Sold1 for the last month but first it must check if sold1 is true, then the same again for Sold2 and Sold3.

My aim is to have the returned data display grouped by AgentName and displayed as:

```
AgentName     TotalSold1       TotalSold2      TotalSold3
```

I hope someone can help as I have spent all day trying to find a solution :(

Comment: Is the `SoldDaten` always `Null` when `Soldn` is `False`?

Answer (score 1):

table_name is the name of the table

```
select t0.AgentName, CountSold1, CountSold2, CountSold3 from (
  select distinct AgentName from table_name
) t0 left join (
  select AgentName, count(*) CountSold1 from table_name
  where Sold1 = 'True' and SoldDate1 between '01-JUN-2012' and '30-JUN-2012'
  group by AgentName
) t1 on t0.AgentName = t1.AgentName left join (
  select AgentName, count(*) CountSold2 from table_name
  where Sold2 = 'True' and SoldDate2 between '01-JUN-2012' and '30-JUN-2012'
  group by AgentName
) t2 on t1.AgentName = t2.AgentName left join (
  select AgentName, count(*) CountSold3 from table_name
  where Sold3 = 'True' and SoldDate3 between '01-JUN-2012' and '30-JUN-2012'
  group by AgentName
) t3 on t2.AgentName = t3.AgentName
```

Comment: should use left join or you will exclude agents that sold nothing in any of the 3 categories

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I am getting an error: syntax error in FROM clause, not sure what could be causing it

Comment: @user1499261 if you are using this solution don't forget to check my answer for a way to get Dates to be variables. With this approach you would have to go change the dates every month.

Comment: @user1499261 substitude `table_name` for the name of your table

Comment: sorry for not responding for so long, I just can't seem to get this to work, the error I am now getting is:
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 't0.AgentDropDown = t1.AgentDropDown left join ( select AgentDropDown, count(*) CountNoPPI2 from MainData where NoPPI2 = 'True'.